# How to find the largest n for which one can solve a problem with a given algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image]

I am working on 15b and 15f.

First I converted the rate to say that 10^9 operations are carried out in one second.

so for

15b. In one second, the largest n would just be 10^9(just n).

But for 15f, what would you do with n!, how would you use algebra to reason this?

Answer (score 0):

Find the smallest $n$ so that $n! > 10^9$. Then $n-1$ is the answer. Factorial grows incredibly fast so a calculator should easily get you the answer in a reasonable number of steps. For example it is easy to see that $n < 18$.

Comment: shouldn't it be the greatest n such that n!<= 10^9